# How to route to different component based on the params

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a use case to create a dashboard and also if there is a dashboard route to that component.

I need to implement the create dashboard route( dashboard route for a given dashboard id is already developed. However when I pass the path, react router does not seem to be able to distinguish between the routes. How can I do that.

```
<Router>
    <div>
        <Switch>
            <Route path="/dashboard/new" exact component={CreateDashboardPage}/>
            <Route path="/dashboard/:dashboardId" exact component={DashboardPage} />
            <Route component={NotFoundPage}/>
        </Switch>
    </div>
</Router>
```

Comment: Which component is displayed when you go to `/dashboard/new`?

Comment: both right now. one below the other

Comment: Can you create a minimal sandbox? As your current code looks fine.

Comment: @leo As you're using `Switch`, the statement: "both right now. one below the other" is impossible. Show us your actual code or supply a reproducible sample that we can see and test.